# Recreating raw data from percentages: How do I randomly assign categories to create data?

Tags: r, apply, sample

The data I'm working with concerns observations by 30 individuals for 60 cases. I have a list of percentages for 4 categories as my starting point. The objective is to work backwards and re-create the raw data.

For eg, case 33 was classified by 13%, 64%, 23% and 0% of 30 observers as '1', '2', '3', and '4', respectively.

```
      [1]  [2]  [3]  [4]
[33,]  13   64   23   0
[34,]   6   84   10   0
[35,]   7   55   38   0
[36,]   6   37   57   0
[37,]  44   34   21   0
[38,]   9   13   54  24
```

The order is not important; in fact it is preferable that random observers categorize case 33 as '1', '2' etc. The important thing is, they should all add up roughly to the percentages, as stated.

I wrote a function that can do this for a single instance (please ignore the horrible quality):

```
makeobs<-function (d){
  ncases<-round((d/100)*30)
  u<-1:30;u1<-1:30
  n1<-sample(u1, ncases[1]);u2<-u1[!u1 %in% n1]
  n2<-sample(u2, ncases[2]);u3<-u2[!u2 %in% n2]
  n3<-sample(u3, ncases[3]);u4<-u3[!u3 %in% n3]
  n4<-u4;
  u[n1]<-1;u[n2]<-2;u[n3]<-3;u[n4]<-4
  u
}
```

If `d` is `c(12, 64, 23, 0)`, `makeobs` returns the following result:

```
> d<-c(13, 64, 23, 0)
> makeobs(d)
 [1] 1 2 1 2 3 3 2 2 2 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 1 2 2 2 2 1 2 3 3 2 2 3 2
> table(makeobs(d))

 1  2  3 
 4 19  7
```

Evidently the function appears to work for a vector of percentages. But when I use `apply` on the matrix of 60 cases, it doesn't.

This is the error message:

> Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) cannot take a
>   sample larger than the population when 'replace = FALSE'

What am I doing wrong? I want to both be able to finally solve this problem and learn why I am wrong. Any help appreciated!

Comment: How exact do you need to be? `round((d/100)*30)` won't necessarily sum to 30 due to rounding error. Do you want to draw from a similar distribution? Or are you trying to recover those exact proportions with a single sample?

Comment: I thnk you can replace your `makeods` function with just `sample(4, 30, replace = TRUE, prob = d/100)`?

Comment: What @DavidArenburg said will extract 1:4 with the given probabilities, but won't necessarily reproduce the exact proportions. If you want to preserve the proportions, try `makeobs<-function(d) {nc<-round(d/100*30);sample(rep(seq_along(nc),nc))}`. Keep also in mind what MrFlick said: this last method won't always produce 30 samples.

Comment: I know this isn't relevant to your question, but I'm curious as to the sequence of events that led you to have a set of percentages of 30 categorizations, rather than the actual categorization counts totalling 30. Did someone lose data somewhere along the line? That's really the underlying issue; you should never have to work backwards to recreate raw data.

Comment: MrFlick, nicola, I understand there will be rounding errors. I tried `round`, 'floor', 'ceiling', 'trunc'; 'round' seems to work the best. The result need to be very accurate, just a rough match would do.

Comment: bgoldst, I am trying to recreate data from a paper. The paper has a figure with the percentages. I am working backwards to recreate raw data in order to perform alternate analysis. (I wrote to the author of the paper, who did not refuse to give data, but did not volunteer it either). Having pseudo-data whose properties are consistent with the published paper is sufficient for the analysis I have in mind.

Comment: nicola, `makeobs<-function(d) {nc<-round(d/100*30);sample(rep(seq_along(nc),nc))}` works. I resampled the results just to be sure it was all random.